# weak solution for a simple boundary problem

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, boundary-value-problem

Consider a smooth, bounded and convex domain $K$ in $R^n$ such that $K\subset \{ x_1 = 0 \}$ and $\Omega $ a bounded convex domain (not necessarily smooth) such that $\partial \Omega \supset K$.

Exists $u: \overline{\Omega} \rightarrow R$ where 
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
\Delta u = 0,  \ in \  \Omega (\ in \ the \ weak \ sense\ ) \\
\hspace{-1.5cm}u = 1 \ in \  K \ (\ pointwise \ ) \\
\hspace{-0.7cm}u = 0 \  on  \ \partial \Omega - K (pointwise) \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

?

I am making this question because in this article (in page 2) http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/12/87/60/PDF/fbpLaplacian.pdf , the author says the answer is positive when $\Omega$ is smooth, but i believe that he did a typo (in relation of the smoothness). I dont know if the answer for my question is positive. I believe the answer is positive because of the variational methods. But i dont know much about variational methods.

Someone can give me a help with my question or say to me a reference ?

My english is terrible sorry..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution of $\Delta u=0$ in the weak sense is also a solution in the classical sense ([Weyl's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_lemma_%28Laplace_equation%29)).

What you wrote in the question is not what they write in the paper.  In the paper, $u$ is not defined on $\overline{\Omega}$, it is defined on $\Omega$. The Dirichlet problem with discontinuous boundary condition is not  fulfilled pointwise:  it is **not** true that $u\to 1$ as $x\to x_0\in K$, for every $x_0\in K$.  What they mean is that $u_\Omega$ is the  [harmonic measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_measure) of $K$. They prefer not to discuss its properties or existence, because they assume the reader knows what it is. The discontinuous boundary conditions can be understood in the $H^1_0$ sense, or in the sense of [Perron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron_method). Some references:

- Kellogg, O. D. (1953), Foundations of potential theory
- Landkof, N. S. (1972), Foundations of modern potential theory